# What is a binary null character?

Tags: c#

I have a requirement to create a sysDesk log file. In this requirement I am supposed to create an XML file, that in certain places between the elements contains a binary null character.

Can someone please explain to me, firstly what is a binary null character, and how can I write one to a text file?

Comment: Just to clarify, you want it to be some special filetype and _not_ a well-formed XML file?

Comment: @Henk, the structure looks like XML, but its going to be digested by SyDesk, so I think you're correct, it won't be well formed.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I suspect it means Unicode U+0000. However, that's [not a valid character in an XML file](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#charsets)... you should see if you can get a very clear specification of the file format to work out what's actually required. Sample files would also be useful :)

Comments are failing me at the moment, so to address a couple of other answers:

- It's not a string termination character in C#, as C# doesn't use null-terminated strings. In fact, all .NET strings *are* null-terminated for the sake of interop, but more importantly the length is stored independently. In particular, a C# string can *entirely validly* include a null character without terminating it:

  ```
  string embeddedNull = "a\0b";
  Console.WriteLine(embeddedNull.Length); // Prints 3
  ```
- The method given by rwmnau for getting a null character or string is very inefficient for something simple. Better would be:

  ```
  string justNullString = "\0";
  char justNullChar = '\0';
  ```

Comment: Hi Jon, if you get a chance, does that mean I don't need to explicitly define a null terminator, because ALL C# strings are already null terminated?

Comment: JL: C# strings happen to be null terminated *in memory* for the sake of interop (at least on the MS CLR), but they're not null terminated in terms of the characters you can actually get at. Whether or not you explicitly need to define one will depend on what you're trying to do - if you're trying to delimit strings, you'll need *some* sort of delimiter.

Answer (score 15):

A binary null character is just a char with an integer/ASCII value of 0.

You can create a null character with `Convert.ToChar(0)` or the more common, more well-recognized `'\0'`.

Comment: Or just `var x = (char)0;`;

Answer (score 2):

A binary NULL character is one that's all zeros (0x00 in Hex). You can write:

```
System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetChars(new byte[] {00});
```

to get it in C#.

Answer (score 2):

The null character is the special character that's represented by U+0000 (encoded by all-zero bits). The null character is represented in C# by the escape sequence `\0`, as in `"This string ends with a null character.\0"`.