# Find Special Character Sequence in file

Tags: c#, file

I have a file that uses NUL's and SOH as markers. I need to look at the pattern of those special characters in order to parse out what I need. For example, when the file is viewed in Notepad++:
**NULNULNUL**   Boom Boom**SOHNULNULNULNULDLENULNULNULSI**John Lee Hooker**SOH**

I would like to extract the "Boom Boom" and the "John Lee Hooker". Those values will change (these are music files) with each file. 
I was thinking of usiing the "NULNULNUl" pattern to find the first section and the "NULSI" to find the second part.
I tried a FileStream to read in the bytes, but i don't know how to detect the special characters.

Comment: [What is a binary null character?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1488060/what-is-a-binary-null-character). Please show relevant code.

Comment: Odds are the header is in a fixed format/struct. Have you tried finding that format and reading it directly?

Comment: Why use those markers? Why not have each string in its own line? And btw, it's "NULs" not "NUL's". ^_^